# How to render components based on localStorage value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

How do I render based on the data in the localStorage? The localStorage has a key-value pair (location: US or Location: AU) and is added when the user visits.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';

let localUserLoc = userLoc;  //works fine when I set this variable to 'US' or 'AU'

const LoadSections= (props) => {
  const { sections, className } = props;

  const [userLoc, setUserLoc] = useState(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('userLoc')) || '');

  useEffect(() => {
    const userLoc = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('userLoc'));
    setUserLoc(userLoc);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserLoc = userLoc;
  }, [userLoc]);

  // // console.log(local1, 'outside');
  console.log(abTestType, '4 - outside');


  return (

    <Wrapper className={className}>

      {sections.map((section, sectionIndex) => {

        const userLocProp = section.userLoc;


        if (userLocProp === localUserLoc) {

          return <SomeComp />
        }

        else if (userLocProp === 'undefined') {
          return <AnotherComp />
        }
```

The code above only loads the  if I manually set the localUserLoc to 'US' or 'AU'. However, when I try to update the variable from localStorage it doesn't display .

I think it is because the LocalStorage is read but not rendered? I tried using two UseEffect hooks and added the first one as a dependency but to no avail.

How can I read and then set the localUserLoc variable to whatever it is in the localStorage and render the relevant component?

- The user loc is detected via IP and then I setItem in localStorage.

Comment: why do you `JSON.stringify` the value returned by `localStorage.getItem` ?

Comment: @Sedenion thanks mate, that was the issue. I had used `JSON.parse` didn't work either. Just doing `localStorage.getItem('key')` did the work.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you are using `JSON.stringify` after getting the value from `localStorage` but the value stored in `localStorage` is already a string because `localStorage` can only store string values.

So you have to use `JSON.parse` for getting the value from `localStorage` and convert it to a `javascript object`.

```
const [userLoc, setUserLoc] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userLoc'))
```

Comment: Thanks Dharmik, for some reason `JSON.parse` didn't work for me. I got the item without parsing